# Can make the 'deleted answers' section in the help more accurate?

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, moderation, help-center

There is a little part of explanation missing in the help center section ['Why and how are some answers deleted?'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

It explains very clearly that moderators can delete any answer and that 10K users can vote-to-delete.

Later, this is the text on undeletion:

> However, deleted posts can be undeleted by casting undelete votes. Once a post has 3 undelete votes, it will no longer be deleted.

This is true, for all answers that are deleted by *regular users*, but not for answers that were removed by *moderators*.

Is it possible to update this text with something like this:

> Only moderators can undelete answers that were removed by moderators.

Comment: There is a link to the faq which explains all.

Comment: I guess that is true for a lot of things. There is an inconsistency in the 'vote to delete' and 'vote to undelete' explanation. I suggest to equal that out.

Comment: Ok, I would agree.

Comment: That doesn't mean I would disagree removing the 10K explanation if that is considered the better option. The explanation is incomplete now.